# Suppose A is a real diagonizable matrix with eigenvalues $\lvert λ\vert \geq2$. Show that there is an invertible real matrix B such that $B+B^{-1} =A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Basically what the title says,I seemingly can't find the solution but here's my progress if it helps;
1.You can easily show that if such a matrix B exists it is interchangeable with A in multiplication, and that $B+B^{-1}=BAB^{-1}$ .
2.Selecting an eigenvalue λ and an eigenvector X we get this from the given equation;
$$(B+B^{-1})X=AX$$ $$BX+B^{-1}X=λX$$ $$(B^2-λB+I)X=0$$
Now what's interesting is that in order to factorize the trinomial you need $\lvert λ\rvert \geq2$. Then you get $$(B-\frac{λ+\sqrt {λ^2-4}}2I)(B-\frac{λ-\sqrt {λ^2-4}}2I)X=0$$
And from there ( I think ) you get that X is an eigenvector of B, either of $\frac{λ+\sqrt {λ^2-4}}2$ or $\frac{λ-\sqrt {λ^2-4}}2$. Anyway I don't know how to proceed from here so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace diagonalizable with diagonal (i.e., conjugate with a suitable matrix) and you are done because every diagonal entry can be written as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is diagonalizable, in a suitable basis, $A$ is diagonal with $\{\lambda_j\}$ as the diagonal entries. Take $B$ diagonal with diagonal entries $\{x_j\}$ where $x_j + x_j^{-1} = \lambda_j$.

Comment: Problem is, I'm not connecting the matrix to a function so I can't exactly choose a basis, but it's the same thing overall regardless of the basis- just multiply it with P and $P^{-1}$